How to create and use SCSS files module-wise in an Angular NX application?
I am building a theme-based Angular application using the Nx Framework, and I am trying to organize styles in a modular fashion for better scalability and maintainability.
Here’s my scenario:
I have predefined SASS variables and mixins in a separate file (e.g., _variables.scss and _mixins.scss, Color, typography) shared across the application.
I have modules such as:Home,Tools,Settings,Interface
For each module, I have created separate SCSS files to handle their specific styles:
home.scss, tools.scss, settings.scss, interface.scss
Currently, I have a global style.The SCSS file includes the common styles and predefined variables/mixins.
My goal is:

To load and use the SCSS files (home.scss, tools.scss, etc.) only within their respective modules, without affecting the global styles.scss.
To make sure the predefined SASS variables and mixins are still accessible within these module-specific SCSS files.
To ensure that the styles are encapsulated and do not bleed into other modules.

Any examples, suggestions, or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
